# Button is not working when placed on background image for HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, sass

I am having trouble with my button being clickable. The main goal I am trying to achieve is to make the button clickable with a background image and what's going on is the button isn't clickable right now.

If anyone can help it would greatly be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Macondo", cursive;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.fas.fa-pause-circle {
  display: none;
}

#wrapper {
  background-image: url("../images/gundam.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bgMusic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 64%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579546929518-9e396f3cc809?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjExMDk0fQ&w=1000&q=80");
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
}

header #content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

header #content h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

header #content h1 span {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FF0000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  header #content h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header #content h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  header #content h1 {
    font-size: 56px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  header #content h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
  }
}

header #content h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #FDFEFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 43%;
}

header #content #countdown {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  header #content #countdown {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header #content #countdown {
    font-size: 56px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  header #content #countdown {
    font-size: 72px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  header #content #countdown {
    font-size: 88px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&family=Macondo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- <link href="/css/all.min.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->

  <title>Mobile Suit Gundam</title>
</head>

<body>
  </div>
  <header>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Mobile<span>Suit</span>Gundam</h1>
        <h2>Coming Soon!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="bgMusic">
        <audio src="music/music.mp3" loop=""></audio>
        <button class="btn">
              <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-pause-circle"></i>
            </button>
      </div>
  </header>
  </div>
  <!-- <script src="js/main.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".btn .fa-play-circle").click(function() {
        $(".bgMusic audio").trigger('play');
        $(".btn .fa-play-circle").hide();
        $(".btn .fa-pause-circle").show();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: have you loaded jquery anywhere? I don't see you including jquery but you are using jquery style javascript. Also, you aren't adding the click handler to your button, you are adding it to the icon tag in the button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a background image. You have an overlay mask as a pseudo-element which blocks access to everything underneath. If you want to keep that layout you can add `pointer-events: none` to it to let clicks pass through, as I've done here.

Note that I've fixed up your HTML, which had a faulty opening div tag and a missing closing div tag. A good editor will make that kind of mistake apparent so you can fix them.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Macondo", cursive;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.fas.fa-pause-circle {
  display: none;
}

#wrapper {
  background-image: url("../images/gundam.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bgMusic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 64%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579546929518-9e396f3cc809?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjExMDk0fQ&w=1000&q=80");
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none; /* <--------------------- I'm your huckleberry */
}

header #content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

header #content h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

header #content h1 span {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FF0000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  header #content h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header #content h1 {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  header #content h1 {
    font-size: 56px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  header #content h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
  }
}

header #content h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #FDFEFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 43%;
}

header #content #countdown {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  header #content #countdown {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header #content #countdown {
    font-size: 56px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  header #content #countdown {
    font-size: 72px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  header #content #countdown {
    font-size: 88px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&family=Macondo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- <link href="/css/all.min.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->

  <title>Mobile Suit Gundam</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <header>
      <div id="content">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <h1>Mobile<span>Suit</span>Gundam</h1>
          <h2>Coming Soon!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="bgMusic">
          <audio src="music/music.mp3" loop=""></audio>
          <button class="btn">
            <i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-pause-circle"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: everything seems good but the music isn't playing when the button is pressed

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Your question doesn't ask about button _functionality_. It asks about clickability. Also, you haven't tagged jQuery, and you haven't loaded jQuery into your page, which explains the console error in the demo in your question.

Comment: my apologies didn't mean too

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Jquery.
You can do it by adding this line inside the head section.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-w8CvhFs7iHNVUtnSP0YKEg00p9Ih13rlL9zGqvLdePA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Jquery official site: https://releases.jquery.com/

Comment: We know what you have currently. You showed us way up there. But _you haven't loaded jQuery_.

Comment: would I put all my Js in the jQuery section then?

Comment: Actually you need to add this line inside the head section, so than your browser you load the Jquery module for you.

Comment: You also need to modify the function to be able to pause the audio.

Comment: @isherwood, I took it from an old file here.
I'll update it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding listener on your icon instead of button.

```
$(".btn .fa-play-circle").click
```

Try using this

```
$(".btn").click
```